# What's the meaning of "with cold winters" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Temperate climate is generally warm during the summer **with cold winters**.

Original article : https://www.reference.com/science/temperate-climate-390b94c325f6d5bb

I'm not sure it means "the summer and cold winters."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the climate is warm during the summer and cold during the winter. **With cold winters** means that the temperate climate is cold during winters or it brings in winters which are cold (both mean the same).

Comment: So here, "with cold winters"="and cold during winters"? It's quite difficult to understand. I've never heard of the usage of 'with'. Could you explain this more?

Comment: @TINGCHOE, **with** has been used to make the sentence have a nice ring to it. If there are warm summers that are followed by cold winters, we can write it as "warm summers with cold winters". You can check this answer, where another example having use of "with" has been used: [link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/63049/49346)

Comment: Thank you. Now I quite understand. 'With' can be used as if conjunction linking two ideas.

Comment: @TINGCHOE if you find my answer helpful, please mark it as the correct answer so that it can help others reading the question.